# Slow insert() using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, insert

**Here is the issue** :

If the collection has only the default index "_id", then the time to upload a set of documents is constant when the collection gets bigger.

But if I add the following index to the collection :

```
db.users.createIndex({"s_id": "hashed"}, {"background": true})
```

then, the time to upload the same set of documents increase drastically (it looks like an exponential function)

**Context :**

I'm trying to insert about 80 millions documents in a collection. I don't use mongo's sharding, there is only one instance.

I'm using the python API and here is my code :

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient(ip_address, 27017)
users = client.get_database('local')\
    .get_collection('users')

bulk_op = users.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()

for s in iterator:
    bulk_op.insert(s)

bulk_op.execute()
client.close()
```

There are 15 concurrent connections (I'm using Apache Spark and it corresponds to the different partitions).

The instance has 4GB of RAM.
The total size of indexes is about 1,5GB when upload is finish.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: For best performance, it would be best to add that index _after_ you've inserted the 80M docs.

Comment: Since you are calculating hash index, there will be alot of collisions over time as you add more documents. MongoDB has to resolve those hash collisions so it's natural taking more time as compared to standard index. However, as @JohnnyHK mentioned, it's better to created index at end of your import.

Comment: Ok thanks. What if I want to replace the insert by an upsert ? In this case I need the index to find the element but it slows down the upload. Is there a solution for a fast upsert ?